# How to exchange an authorization code for an access token (Oauth 2.0) using HTTP/REST in Java?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I would like to authorize my server to access to application-specific data on the Google Drive of my client. Therefore I need to use OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications. I followed the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#handlingresponse) provided by Google. However I failed to pass step 5 (exchange an authorization code for an access token). Everytime I get: Error 400 Bad Request.

I tried to see if the code that was passed in my request expired. However, as I use my code directly when I get it, it doesn't seem to be the issue. I also checked if my redirect_uri was authorized in the Google Console for this client id.

```
@GET
@Path("get-oauth-google-drive/{email}/{token}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getOauthGoogleDrive(
        @PathParam("email") String email,
        @PathParam("token") String token
) {
    String linkForOauth = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=" + client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + domain + "/rest/myresource/callback&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata&access_type=offline";
    return linkForOauth;
}

@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("granted-callback")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String callbackGranted(
        String  msg
) {
    System.out.println("Drive Access GRANTED");
    return "";
}

@GET
@Path("callback")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String callbackOauth(
        @QueryParam("code") String code,
        @QueryParam("scope") String scope
) {
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        InputStream inputStream = getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        GoogleClientSecrets googleClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String clientId = googleClientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId();
        String clientSecret = googleClientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret();
        String redirectURI = domain + "/rest/myresource/granted-callback";
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", code));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", clientId));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", clientSecret));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", URLEncoder.encode(redirectURI, "UTF-8")));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Merci de votre inscription vous allez être redirigé incessamment sous peu.";
}
```

Steps 1, 2, 3 and 4 are working fine but step 5 is always writing Error 400 Bad Request. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Have you tried logging the POST request you're sending? Maybe it's malformatted

Comment: If you are getting 400 Bad Request, the response should contain some info about why the request failed. See the [OAuth2 RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5.2). Can you update your question with the response body?

Comment: I have the following body for my response : 
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme: https%3A%2F%2Faccount.*************.com%2Frest%2Fmyresource%2Fgranted-callback"
}

Comment: Ok so I fixed my issue by using a non-encrypted URL. Thank you for your help